# Is there a way to distinguish habitualis from generic interpretation?

Tags: semantics, linguistic-typology

I'm looking for a way to classify a given sentence as either habitualis or generic in a language where neither is a grammatical category. Thus, it should be a some semantic feature of the sentence.

Both are some kind of extending an event "into customary or usual practice", as Frawley (2013) puts it. Can it be, for instance, that habitual is rather used to predicate a property of an individual, while generic -- of a kind? Or do they differ in that the former, but not the latter, has an existential presupposition?

As an example, consider this:

(1) Whenever I see John, he's wearing a black coat.

I'm grateful for any ideas!

A few remarks are in order. I don't mean the readings of NPs here, rather the whole sentence as a context that, in (1) licences *whenever*. Also, I consider (2) a prototypical example of habitualis, and (3) of generic:

(2) Bill used to drink in the morning.

(3) Cows eat grass.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You have to distinguish between nouns and verbs first. There are generic [active verb usages](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html), like _Bill walks to work_ and _That dog bites_; the nouns are all referential but the verbs are generic. And then there are [generic NPs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), like _The tiger has stripes_ and _A madrigal is polyphonic_. They're quite often used together, but they're not the same. Also, I have no idea why one would want to use "habitual" as an antonym for "generic". Most generic verb usage is habitual, at least with an agent subject.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Carlson 2012 might interest you http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780195381979.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780195381979-e-29